# Determining critical points of this convoluted equation

Tags: calculus

I am asked to find the critical points of this function: $$2x^6 + 9x^5 + 10x^4 -13x - 5$$
I found the derivative to be $12x^5 + 45x^4 + 40x^3 - 13$. However I have no idea how to find $f(x) = 0$. How can I solve for the $x$ in this equation?? It's the first time I have to solve one so complicated.

Comment: you may use a numerical method

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct function to study? According to wolframalpha, the roots of your last polynomial do not have a nice form..

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, like?

Comment: The second derivative has a nice form, at least you can get the inflection points. $$f''(x)=60x^2(x+2)(x+1)$$

Comment: Newton Raphson method

Comment: Very scarcely dependable. (I knew it, but as Newton's Method!) @Dr.SonnhardGraubner.

Comment: not all in the world have a nice form!

Comment: see here http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der07/der07.html

Comment: This looks complicated. Is there any other way to do it? :-/

Comment: I wanted to say that it has some loopholes and doesn't work everytime. @Dr.SonnhardGraubner.

Comment: The second derivative has a nice form..See my comment above.

Comment: And how can I determine the critical points with the inflection points?

Comment: [Plotting](http://www.fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIyKnheNis5KnheNSsxMCp4XjQtMTMqeC01IiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwLCJ3aW5kb3ciOlsiLTEwLjE1Mzg0NjE1Mzg0NjE1MyIsIjkuODQ2MTUzODQ2MTUzODQ3IiwiLTI3LjQwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMiIsIjEwMCJdfV0-) gives you a first indication where to look.